# Functions with different value of default arguments

Tags: c++, default-arguments

How to parse function arguments, when all have default values and only some of them are used?
Example:
I have a function with several arguments with default values

```
void fun(string a="", int b=0, string c="", int d=0)
{
 //parse used arguments somehow
}
```

I want to use it with different value of arguments, for example:

```
fun("foo", 10);
fun(10, 10);
```

How can I determine which arguments were used? Maximum value of arguments is known and order will be always the same.
I do not want to run function like:

```
fun("", 3, "", 10);
```

And I cannot use variadic functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: "How can I determine which arguments were used?" You can't. I'm also fairly certain `fun(10, 10);` will either not compile as 10 is not a string, or will not do what you expect (it'll probably assume 10 is a pointer to a char*)

Comment: @Borgleader, Nah, it won't compile. `std::string` deliberately made sure of that.

Comment: @chris It will if you call with 0 instead like so [`foo(0, 10);`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cef36eb5e16b0bbf) which is a really nasty bug source in this case.

Comment: @Borgleader, For 0, yes. That's extremely unfortunate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload the function.

```
void fun(int b, int d) { fun("", b, "", d); }
```

Then `fun(3, 10)` becomes equivalent to `fun("", 3, "", 10)`.